# typescript function throwing error to return a value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Here is what I am trying to accomplish, I am calling a function getGeoLocationOfUser() which I supposed to return me the geolocation of user and function is supposed to return only when geolocation is available or there is some error.

but above function is throwing an error **A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.**

```
  public userGeolocation={latitude:null,longitude:null}

  getGeoLocationOfUser():{latitude:any,longitude:any}{
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    this.userGeolocation.latitude=resp.coords.latitude;
    this.userGeolocation.longitude=resp.coords.longitude;
    console.log(this.userGeolocation);

localStorage.setItem('userGeoLocation',JSON.stringify(this.userGeolocation));
return this.userGeolocation;
 //saving geolocation of user to localStorage

 }).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
  return this.userGeolocation;
});
}
```

I might be missing a very basic concept here .Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Fair enough.@Rob I ended up putting a lot of comments since there were a bunch of answers with issues..People are in a rush being FGITW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a *Promise* of Geolocation here.

```
//Make return type as Promise<object_type> or Promise<any>
 getGeoLocationOfUser():Promise<{latitude:any,longitude:any}>{
   //return the inner function
    return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    this.userGeolocation.latitude=resp.coords.latitude;
    this.userGeolocation.longitude=resp.coords.longitude;
    console.log(this.userGeolocation);

localStorage.setItem('userGeoLocation',JSON.stringify(this.userGeolocation));
return this.userGeolocation;
 //saving geolocation of user to localStorage

 }).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
  return this.userGeolocation;
});
}
```

You can then get the value by calling `function().then(callback)`.

```
 getGeoLocationOfUser().then( loc =>{
     this.location = loc}).catch(err=>{});
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Kindly change the return type `any` instead of  `{latitude:any,longitude:any}`

```
getGeoLocationOfUser(): any {
      return  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
            this.userGeolocation.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
            this.userGeolocation.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
            console.log(this.userGeolocation);
            localStorage.setItem('userGeoLocation', JSON.stringify(this.userGeolocation));
            return this.userGeolocation;
            //saving geolocation of user to localStorage
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error getting location', error);
            return this.userGeolocation;
        });
}
```

Comment: This wont work.. though the arrow function returns value, the arrow function itself is not returned from `getGeoLocationOfUser`

Comment: Worth noting that using `any` should be your last resort when using TypeScript. In this case it is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `any` return type.

```
getGeoLocationOfUser(): Promise<any> {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    this.userGeolocation.latitude=resp.coords.latitude;
    this.userGeolocation.longitude=resp.coords.longitude;
    console.log(this.userGeolocation);

    localStorage.setItem('userGeoLocation',JSON.stringify(this.userGeolocation));
    return this.userGeolocation;
    //saving geolocation of user to localStorage

 }).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
  return this.userGeolocation;
});
}
```

Comment: This wont work.. though the arrow function returns value, the arrow function itself is not returned from `getGeoLocationOfUser` It should return a promise..

Comment: Check my answer.. `return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`